# How do you properly read two JSON arrays with different data points from two seperate links into to one array in php

Tags: php, json

My first post here on Stackoverflow.

How do you properly read two JSON arrays with different data points from two seperate links into to one array in php. The goal here is to have an single array with values from the two seperate JSON datasets to later insert into MySql.

```
Array 
(
    [1] => 'HourDK' value         // Dataset 1
    [2] => 'PriceArea' value      // Dataset 1
    [3] => 'SpotPriceDKK' value   // Dataset 1
    [4] => 'Price1' value         // Dataset 2
)
```

Then 24 arrays, one for each hour sorted by "HourDK". And then later insert this array into MySQL.

Link to my server: http://www.theos-kamp.dk/strom/json.php

Link to Dataset1: https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?start=2023-01-22T00%3A00&end=2023-01-23T00%3A00&columns=HourDK%2C%20PriceArea%2C%20SpotPriceDKK&filter=%7B%22PriceArea%22%3A%20%22DK2%22%7D

Link to Dataset2: https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/DatahubPricelist?start=2023-01-22T00%3A00&end=2023-01-23T00%3A00&filter=%7B%22ChargeOwner%22%3A%20%22TREFOR%20El-net%20A%2FS%22%2C%20%22Note%22%3A%20%22Nettarif%20C%20time%22%7D&limit=1&timezone=DK

My json.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>json</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    // Nordpool pricelist
    $url1 = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?start=2023-01-22T00%3A00&end=2023-01-23T00%3A00&columns=HourDK%2C%20PriceArea%2C%20SpotPriceDKK&filter=%7B%22PriceArea%22%3A%20%22DK2%22%7D';
    // Grid pricelist
    $url2 = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/DatahubPricelist?start=2023-01-22T00%3A00&end=2023-01-23T00%3A00&filter=%7B%22ChargeOwner%22%3A%20%22TREFOR%20El-net%20A%2FS%22%2C%20%22Note%22%3A%20%22Nettarif%20C%20time%22%7D&limit=1&timezone=DK';

    $json1 = file_get_contents($url1);
    $json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
    $json_array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
    $json_array2 = json_decode($json2, true);

    foreach($json_array1 as $key1 => $arrays1){
        
            foreach($arrays1 as $array1){
            echo "<br />";
            print_r(array_values($array1));

        }
            echo "<br />";
    }

    foreach($json_array2 as $key2 => $arrays2){
        
            foreach($arrays2 as $array2){
            echo "<br />";
            print_r(array_values($array2));

        }
            echo "<br />";
    }

    //$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    //print_r($result);
    
    //echo $array1, $array2;

    //foreach ($jo as $value) {
    //echo $jo->records;
    //}
    //echo $value, "\n";
    //echo var_dump($jo)
    //echo $jo->records;

    // Grid pricelist

    
    /*
    $url2 = 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/DatahubPricelist?start=2023-01-22T00%3A00&end=2023-01-23T00%3A00&filter=%7B%22ChargeOwner%22%3A%20%22TREFOR%20El-net%20A%2FS%22%2C%20%22Note%22%3A%20%22Nettarif%20C%20time%22%7D&limit=1&timezone=DK';
    $json = file_get_contents($url2);
    $json_array2 = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($json_array2 as $key => $arrays){
        echo $key . "<br />";
        foreach($arrays as $array){
            echo "<br />";
            foreach($array as $key => $value){
                echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
            }
            echo "<br />";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
    */

    /*
    $Price1 * 1.25 * 100 / 100
    $Price2
    $Price3
    $Price4
    $Price5
    $Price6
    $Price7
    $Price8
    $Price9
    $Price10
    $Price11
    $Price12
    $Price13
    $Price14
    $Price15
    $Price16
    $Price17
    $Price18
    $Price19
    $Price20
    $Price21
    $Price22
    $Price23
    $Price24
    */

    
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I disagree that your question is a duplicate of that "Merging arrays php", they probably only read the title where it very much sounds like it would be a duplicate. If you want to you may edit your question to highlight the specifics and ask for a re-opening.

Comment: Yes i agree with this question is not a dublicate. It sure sounds like that in the title, I will give it a try, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data points in dataset 2 can not be looped through using a foreach you could use a for loop and reach the values via `$var['Price' . $num]`. See example below, let me know if it works out for you.

```
<?php
    $hour_prices = array();

    for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
        $hour_prices[] = array(
            $dataset_1['records'][$hour]['HourDK']
            , $dataset_1['records'][$hour]['PriceArea']
            , $dataset_1['records'][$hour]['SpotPriceDKK']
            , $dataset_2['records'][0]['Price' . ($hour + 1)]
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas, it works allmost flawlesly. It seems like i have an array whitin an array and its causing me trouble i think. `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2023-01-22T23:00:00 [1] => DK2 [2] => 1103.27002 [3] => 0.1397 ) )`

Comment: @nhtj It's perfectly normal to have an array of arrays. Hope your troubles resolves. :)

Comment: Then its most likely not the array thats causing me trouble, but my coding maybe. lol